# Size of array of returned function does not match

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to solve the problem below using python, first time using this language so bear with me please.

I keep getting this error and am unsure of the problem, I have looked at other posts as well but with no success.

I am trying to find the solution to `di/dt=beta-s*i-gamma*i`

where `ds/dt=-beta*s*i`

and

```
R0=beta/gamma

R0=3

gamma=1/10
```

I keep getting

> The size of the array returned by func (1) does not match the size of y0 (3).

Error on the following

```
def F(x,t,R):
    s,i,r = x
    beta = R*gamma    
    di = beta*s*i-gamma*i    
    return di

i_0 = 10
s_0 = 1 - i_0
r_0 = 0
x_0 = s_0, i_0, r_0

def solve_path(R0, t_vec, x_init):
    s_path, i_path, r_path = odeint(F, x_init, t_vec, args=(R0,)).transpose()    
    return s_path, i_path, r_path

t_length = 10
t_vec = np.array([t for t in range(t_length)])
R0 = 3
gamma = 1/10
s_path, i_path, r_path = solve_path(R0, t_vec, x_0)
```

Comment: `F` function return should have the same size as `x_init` (which is the tuple `x_0`)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your ODEs are exactly describing but the problem seems to be that you have three states but only one ODE that you use in your function `F()` and it describes only a single state. The number of states and equations should match if each produces a single state. Similarly I am not sure why `r` is part of the state at all since you are not using it. Are you probably confusing `r` and `R`. If you remove `r` but keep `R` and use both ODEs, you have two states and two equations which should work. Not sure if it does in the end what you want though but at least it runs without error.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def F(x, t, R, gamma):
    s, i = x
    beta = R*gamma
    dids = [beta-s*i-gamma*i, -beta*s*i]
    return dids


i_0 = 10
s_0 = 1 - i_0
x_0 = s_0, i_0

t = np.arange(10)
R0 = 3
gamma = 0.1
s_path, i_path = odeint(F, x_0, t, args=(R0, gamma)).transpose().tolist()
print('s_path', s_path)
print('i_path', i_path)
```

this produces

```
s_path [-9.0, -0.07684886189702785, -0.07734897139441971, -0.07787089670033634, -0.07838416942498759, -0.07888875287370806, -0.0793846544937942, -0.07987187348257006, -0.0803504237076822, -0.08082032372337275]
i_path [10.0, 12.964357349986603, 13.267665037061981, 13.580202991374998, 13.902261853534174, 14.23413149276537, 14.576110670513012, 14.928507352060898, 15.29163875844641, 15.665831792726621]
```

It seems that the delta t in `t` is pretty large maybe you want to try smaller steps with `t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)`.

Btw. `F` and the formula of the first ODE differ slightly (*, -) make sure to use the correct one.